# Wordpress on Reverse Proxy

Tags: php, wordpress, apache, lamp

I have a Wordpress that runs perfectly fine on direction connection and installation.

However, things in Admin panel starts to break when I implement reverse proxy. 2 examples of problem:

- Admin panel, search post will lead to page not found - domain.com/error.html
- Admin panel, save settings will lead to page not found - domain.com/error.html

  Is there any resolution to this? The implementation is this:
- domain.com/application is having a reverse proxy to application.domain.com

Looking forward to the closes cue! Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to ignore the cache/proxy entirely whenever dealing with dynamic content, such as searching, saving settings, adding or editing posts, etc.

Implementing reverse proxies isn't a plug and play sort of situation.  However, plugins do exist that will make your life a lot easier.

There's a good plugin for Varnish (you didn't specify the reverse proxy you're using), that will purge the cache as and when it's needed:

https://wordpress.org/plugins/varnish-wp/

Comment: I'm not entirely sure why this is being downvoted.  OP asks why pages with obvious dynamic content are being 404'd, answer states that it's because they aren't in the cache, so you need to ignore the cache for those pages.  Makes perfect sense, also given a solution to the issue.